# Orientation change in Swift height change and uibutton hide on landscape

Tags: iphone, swift, swift-extensions

I am making one custom keyboard in which when orientation of mobile is changed then in landscape i have to hide one button please suggest how can i do this i am using below code to do this task please help me.
in landscape also the button is visible i want to hide button on landscape and visible in portrait mode

```
override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()

   //  Add custom view sizing constraints here

    var currentDevice: UIDevice = UIDevice.currentDevice()
    var orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = currentDevice.orientation

    if orientation.isLandscape {

     button.hidden = true
     }

    if orientation.isPortrait {
        button.hidden = false
     }
}
```

Comment: You wont get the code here. Please state what your problem is. Don't ask how to code it.

Comment: my problem is orientation is change but in landscape mode also the button is not hidden

Answer (score 1):

In your `viewDidLoad` put

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "orientationChanged", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Then add this method

```
func orientationChanged()
{
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {            
        button.hidden = true
    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        button.hidden = false
    }

}
```

Note:

`UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation` might not give you the correct orientation. You can use the status bar orientation instead `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation`

From the apple docs:

`UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation`

> The value of the property is a constant that indicates the current
>   orientation of the device. This value represents the physical
>   orientation of the device and may be different from the current
>   orientation of your application’s user interface. See
>   “UIDeviceOrientation” for descriptions of the possible values.

Comment: did you try `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation` instead of  `UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation` ?

Comment: No i have not try can you please let me know how to implement this

Comment: The same code Above but replace `UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation` with `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation`

Comment: hi it show error  if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation))

Comment: try `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOri‌​entation)`

Comment: UIApplication does not have a member name 'statusBarOrientation'